# CSS box shadow not working on Chrome

Tags: html, css

CSS `box-shadow` works on Mozilla, but not on Chrome.
If I use the class on div (i.e. div with id `mydiv`) it works!
Why am I not allowed to use box shadow on `tr` tag?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                    
<html lang="en">                                                   
    <head>                                                         
    <style>
        .item_row:hover {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #CCCCCC inset;                 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #CCCCCC inset;            
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #CCCCCC inset;         
        }                                                          
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='mydiv'>
            <table>
                <tr class='item_row'>                              
                <td>test</td>
                </tr>                                              
            </table>                                               
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just tested in Chrome.
Instead of applying your css to the tr, instead apply to the child td:

```
.item_row:hover td {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #CCCCCC inset;                 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #CCCCCC inset;            
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #CCCCCC inset;         
}
```

Comment: Yes. It works on td. Sometimes css doesn't work on logic. Why is it so? Is it because of "less knowledge about css" or "its the way it works and we need to use trial and error".